# Freeform Pro - displaying entries using composer template

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform, solspace, composer, composer-template

I used composer template to drag n drop and make my form.  I have it working fine and allowing a submit.  Now I need to let an admin display each persons application that was submitted through this form so they can print it.  Viewing the forms through the module tab doesn't give a nice print layout like I need.

Is there a way to display all of a specific entry_id entries with the same form layout made from composer template? This is the code I'm using to show the initial form

```
{exp:freeform:composer
     form_name="office_employee_app"
     composer_template_name="office_employee_template"
     return="admin/office-application-signature"
}
```

Comment: Anybody have a solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to display details about form submissions on the front end, you can do it by using the [Freeform:Entries](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/) template tag, and just make sure you're calling the entry_id parameter and providing a value to it:

```
{exp:freeform:entries
    form_id="1"
    entry_id="{segment_3}"
}

    <p>
        Submitted:
        {freeform:entry_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i %a"}
    </p>

    <h3>
        By: {freeform:field:name}
    </h3>

    <p>Email Address: {freeform:field:email}</p>

    <p>Home Phone: {freeform:field:home_phone}</p>

    {if freeform:field:cell_phone}
        <p>Cell Phone: {freeform:field:cell_phone}</p>
    {/if}

    <p>Subject: {freeform:field:subject}</p>
    <p>Questions or Comments:<br />{freeform:field:question}</p>

    {if freeform:no_results}
        <p>No results found.</p>
    {/if}

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

If if I understand you correctly, if you're trying to display the actual values inside an actual form, you could dummy up form fields to hold those values.

And lastly, seeing that you're using Composer, if you're looking for a way to have Freeform auto-populate everything by itself, you could use the [Freeform:Composer_Edit](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/composer_edit/) template tag (and just don't bother editing), and that would save you the work of recreating the form on the front end. :)

Comment: The Freeform:Composer_Edit template tag was exactly what I needed, thank you!  It spits out the initial created form I used via Composer and adds all the entry's data inside the form.  This way the client can print it out nicely in the table format.